# Looker Studio Scorecard Not Showing Correct Date Range Comparison Percentage

Tags: comparison, visualization, looker-studio

I'm encountering an issue with Looker Studio where my scorecard, which is supposed to compare data between two different date ranges, keeps showing 0.0% change. This happens even though there are known differences between the data in the two periods. I am not using calculated fields; this is a direct metric comparison.

**Problem Details**:

- Data source: pipedrive data to Third-party service connected via Coupler.io.
- Metric: Direct metric from the data source.
- Scorecard setup: Shows the total for a given metric with a comparison to the previous period's total.
- Expected behavior: Show the percentage change between the two periods.
- Actual behavior: Constantly shows 0.0% change.

[screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnJI5.jpg)

Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated as this feature is crucial for our data reporting.

Thank you!

- Ensuring the data source is accurate and up-to-date.
- Confirming that the date ranges are correctly set (current month vs. previous month).
- Refreshing the data source and ensuring it is correctly linked.
- Checking for any applied filters that might affect the scorecard.
- Testing the setup with different metrics and date ranges.
- Clearing browser cache and trying different browsers.